# GAE ndb query on user object

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
for car in  Car.query().fetch():
        print car.owner == users.get_current_user()
```

This prints True for all cars owned by the current user, as expected.

```
for car in  Car.query(Car.owner == users.get_current_user()).fetch():
        print car
```

While the current user owns several cars, this returns no results. Why?

Comment: did you try to log the values for `car.owner` and `users.get_current_user()` ? maybe the representation of the two objects is different.

Comment: they both come out as the username

Comment: what about the namespace? do you use different namespaces?

Comment: can you link to usage of the query function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing User objects in the Datastore is fraught with problems; the failing query is just one example (and no, sorry, I don't know why exactly it fails in your case).

You are much better off storing either just the "user ID" (i.e. users.get_current_user().user_id(), a string) or the email address -- depending on what you think should happen if a user changes the email address associated with their Google (GMail) Account.  The user_id remains the same, the email address (obviously) changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've added new cars owned by me and the query is picking those up as expected. This does not answer the technical problem (that is, I still don't understand why the query didn't work) - but it does solve my practical one.